# Location to place Sqlite DB in Flutter

Tags: flutter

A Sqlite DB file has pre existing data, and this needs to be added to a Flutter application, ideally in a way which will work for both Android and iOS.

Have placed the file in the following location:

```
/assets/db/myDB.db
```

`/assets` is a folder in the root, like lib.

**pubspec.yaml** has:

```
 assets:
    - assets/db/
```

The code to open and query the database:

```
 final db = await openDatabase('myDb.db');

 final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE module_id = ?', [moduleId]);
```

An error is being thrown when trying to query the database, although none on opening the database. Even if I change the name of the db to one which does not exist, an error does not appear to be thrown. Tested this by using

```
await openDatabase('name.db')
          .catchError((e) => print('DB BERROR:' + e));
```

Nothing is printed.

What is the correct location to place the db file, so that it will be included when deployed on both Android and iOS?

Thanks

Comment: what error is it?

Comment: You want to ship and existing SQLite Database as a part of your app is it?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Edited the question to detail the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assets is not really a folder in your filesystem.
In order to use it with sqlite, you need to copy the asset to a folder, typically the cache folder of your app.

Here is an example (add path_provider to your pubspec.yaml):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

Future<Database> openDatabaseFromAssets() async {
  // Get the temporary directory (cache)
  final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final path = join(directory.path, 'myDB.db');
  
  // Check if the database file exists
  final exists = await File(path).exists();
  
  if (!exists) {
    // Copy from assets
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/db/myDB.db');
    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    
    // Write and flush the bytes written
    await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  }
  
  // Open the database
  return await openDatabase(path);
}
```

Comment: I have an issue with the code - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78026314/async-function-in-flutter-running-after-the-function-which-calls-it

Comment: The code here is alright, I just tested it. That is another question, so I added a comment there to try to help you.