# async function in Flutter running after the function which calls it

Tags: flutter, dart

The following is a function in a Flutter application which retrieves from a database and maps the result set to objects:

```
class SQLHelper {
  static Future<List<MyObject>> retrieve(int moduleId) async {
    final db = await openDatabaseFromAssets('myTable.db');

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db
        .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE moduleid = ?', [moduleId]);

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return const MyObject(
          // pass result set to MyObject constructor
       );
    });
  }
}

   Future<Database> openDatabaseFromAssets(String dbName) async {
     // PROBLEM IS WITH THIS LINE
     final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();

     final path = join(directory.path, dbName);

     // Check if the database file exists
     final exists = await File(path).exists();

     if (!exists) {
       // Copy from assets
       ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/db/$dbName');
       List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

       // Write and flush the bytes written
       await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
     }

     // Open the database
     return await openDatabase(path);
   }
```

When debugging, the `openDatabaseFromAssets` method is called as expected, but, after the following line is called:

```
directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
```

the debugger stops after the line which calls the `retrieve` method. As no data is yet retrieved, there is a null error. Then, the application continues in the `openDatabaseFromAssets` function, on the line after the call to `getTemporaryDirectory`.

The `retrieve` method is called as follows:

```
Future<List<MyObject>> getMyObjects(int moduleId) async {
   List<MyObject> list = await SQLHelper.retrieve(moduleId);
   return list;
}
```

The `getMyObjects` function is called as follows:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int moduleId = 1;
    List<MyObject>? myList;
    getMyObjects(moduleId).then((value) => myList = value);
    // next line continues before getMyObjects has finished
```

**NOTE: I cannot add async before the call to getMyObjects, because the build() method is not async - it returns a Widget and not a Future**

`getTemporaryDirectory` is defined in `path_provider.dart`.

In **pubspec.yaml**, db path is declared as follows:

```
  assets:
    - assets/db/
```

What could account for this?

Thanks

Comment: _"What is the correct way to call a function which returns a Future, so that the result the Future contains will be available to the next line of code?"_: Using `await` is already the correct way.

Comment: `await` already does this. My feeling is that the error probably lies inside `openDatabaseFromAssets`. Maybe missing an `await` inside of it, but hard to judge if you don't show us the implementation

Comment: You are correct - the issue is in the implementation of that method, am editing the question - thanks

Comment: in the `openDatabaseFromAssets ` you are not opening and returning the database obj.

Comment: Thanks, had not pasted those lines in the question - edited the question, that is not however the issue

Comment: Have you declared the db path of assets folder in the pubspec.yaml file? Like `assets/db/` directory of your Flutter project, and it's declared in the pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: Yes - edited question to include snippet from pubspec.yaml

Comment: Your getMyObjects must be async if you need it to return a result from another async function. As it is, you are making an async call and returning a result before the async function finishes.

Comment: does not solve the issue - modified the question. build method of the Widget which calls getMyObjects continues before the result from getMyObjects has been returned.

Comment: As I added in the question, I cannot add await before a function which returns a Future in the build() method which is not async

Comment: you shouldn't be calling an async function on a build method. For that, there is FutureBuilder

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: when you call future.then it does not wait the result, it only register a callback code. That's why you are always getting null errors. FutureBuilder also make sure you can place a user friendly message that the database is being loaded or a fail message.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help. This works great - apart from the fact that very often - not always - there is a slight flicker on the page, presumably as the data loads. I have to fix that .

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an issue in the query retrieving list type in the `retrieve` function. Try with dynamic map list type, like below:

```
static Future<List<MyObject>> retrieve(int moduleId) async {
    Database? db;
    db = await openDatabaseFromAssets('myDB.db');
    if(db == null) {
     print("error in db opening");
     return [];
    }
    else {
     final List<Map> maps = await db
        .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE moduleid = ?', [moduleId]);

     return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return const MyObject(
          // pass result set to MyObject constructor
       );
     });
    }
}

Future<List<MyObject>> getMyObjects(int moduleId) async {
   List<MyObject> list = await SQLHelper.retrieve(moduleId);
   return list;
}


FutureBuilder(
    future: getMyObjects(1),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
         return YourWidget();
      } else {
         return const CupertinoActivityIndicator();
      }
    },
)
```

Comment: the query is ok, and returns the correct number of rows, it's just that it does not run immediately after the database is opened, but rather after the call to the retrieve() merhod

Comment: Modified getMyObects and updated it in the question as well, but it does not solve the issue. As I added in the question, I cannot add await before a function which returns a Future in the build() method which is not async

Comment: You should use `FutureBuilder` widget then and call the `getMyObjects` as future in it instead of calling in the build method.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your help. This works great - apart from the fact that very often - not always - there is a slight flicker on the page, presumably as the data loads. I have to fix that .

Comment: You can show loader in `futurebuilder` until the data is fetch from the database.

Comment: Could you show a blank canvas in the loader to remove the flicker? The retrieval from Sqlite is very fast. Or is PageWithFutureBuilder a better solution?

Answer (score -2):

The problem might be with the use of `const` in the `List.generate` method, as you cannot use const with asynchronous operations.

Here's the corrected code:

```dart
class SQLHelper {
  static Future<List<MyObject>> retrieve(int moduleId) async {
    late Database db;
    db = await openDatabaseFromAssets('myDB.db');

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE moduleid = ?', [moduleId]);

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return MyObject(
        // pass result set to MyObject constructor
        
      );
    });
  }
}

Future<Database> openDatabaseFromAssets(String dbName) async {
  // open the database and return it
}
```